# Does Broken Blade's Pugilist stance and Monk's Unarmed Strike Stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, unarmed-combat

I've taken a fascination with Pathfinder and its *Path of War* supplement.
I've also grown quite attached to the Bladebound magus, the Sacred Fist warpriest and the Sandman bard but that's beside the point.

I notice that the *broken blade* discipline from *Path of War* is generally about one thing:  hitting things really really hard. I also noticed that it has a feat list called *martial training* that allows non-*Path of War* classes to learn things from one specific discipline.

So..combine monks *unarmed strike* progression with *pugilist stance* on top of *pummeling strike* and *charge*, and it looks lethal.  I want to make sure that this IS legal to do.   (More so *that its legal to do within the rules of the game* not that it won't work).

I want to make sure that

- the two effects stack with each other
- this is legal within the rules

Why? When you have a monk pummeling charging at you with a flurry of blows that will hit for 4d6+ strength mod, potentially on top of something like divine power, you'll make some enemies really quick (The *pummeling style* feat).

Comment: Its not so much that i don't  think it would work, I just wanna make sure that the 2 effects stack with each others and is legal within the rules, cause when you have a monk pummeling charging at you with a flurry of blows that will hit for 4d6+ w/e your strength mod is potentially on top of something like divine power, You're gonna make some enemies really quick i imagine

Comment: Is pummeling strike a maneuver absent from the *d20PFSRD* and in *Path of War* or do you mean the feats Pummeling Style et al.?

Comment: The pummeling style feat

Comment: @masakan please fold those details into the question, as the detail is of interest.   I have made a rough edit but you probably need to clean it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It's legit, complicated, and about as powerful as it should be

A [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Bonus-Feat) that takes the archetype [master of many styles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/master-of-many-styles/) can take at level 1 as its monk bonus feat the feat [Pummeling Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-style-combat-style/), take at level 2 as its monk bonus feat [Pummeling Charge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-charge-combat/), take at level 5 the feat [Martial Training I](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/#TOC-Martial-Training-I-Combat-) and at level 7 the feat [Martial Training II](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/#TOC-Martial-Training-II-Combat-). Such a monk at level 7 can charge and, at the charge's end, unleash his full [flurry of blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-) of unarmed attacks—that's 3 (4 is but a level away) that each deal 1d8 + Strength modifier points of damage and an extra +1d6 points of damage—on a lone foe. This is *acceptable* but by no means *remarkable*, the archetype mandates playing a ([not unchained](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87272/8610)) [monk](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26977/8610), and such a character might be better served by multiclassing into the base class [brawler](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47849/8610).

Speaking of brawler, a creature can instead take at level 1 the base class [brawler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/) (which has its own unarmed strike damage progression), at level 3 take the feat [Martial Training I](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/#TOC-Martial-Training-I-Combat-), at level 5 take the feat [Martial Training II](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/#TOC-Martial-Training-II-Combat-) (picking the Broken Blade discipline and this second feat allowing the brawler to take the stance [pugilist stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Pugilist-Stance) which the GM may rule scales as [the table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/) describes rather than not scale as per its [description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Pugilist-Stance)), at level 6 employ the brawler class feature [martial flexibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/#TOC-Martial-Flexibility-Ex-) to gain temporarily the feat [Pummeling Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-style-combat-style/) until at level 7 that feat can be taken permanently, and—finally!—at level 12 *again* employ the brawler class feature martial flexibility to gain temporarily the feat [Pummeling Charge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-charge-combat/) until at level 13 *that* feat can be taken permanently.

Then, at level 13, the brawler can charge and, at the charge's end, unleash his full [brawler's flurry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/#TOC-Brawler-s-Flurry-Ex-) of unarmed attacks—that's 3 from the brawler's base attack bonus and another 2 from the virtual Two-weapon Fighting and Improved Two-weapon Fighting feats that all deal 2d6 points of damage and an extra +2d6 points of damage—against a lone foe. Assuming a decent Strength score, the feat [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat---final), and maybe a [magical buff](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) or two, this is pretty okay and about where a creature of that experience level *should* be.

(Keep in mind that [pugilist stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Pugilist-Stance) deals extra dice of damage, and that extra dice of damage, for example, are not multiplied on a critical hit (see [Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/) on Multiplying Damage). Thus a level 13 brawler like the one above on a typical hit deals with his unarmed strike 2d6 + his Strength modifier +1d6 or 2d6 points of damage depending on the GM rules on Pugilist Stance, but on a typical *critical* hit with his unarmed strike he deals 4d6 + twice his Strength modifier +1d6 or 2d6 points of damage, *not* 6d6 or 8d6 + twice his Strength modifier!)

Comment: dont forget it scales albeit more slowly it would still be 2d6 bonus damage by the time you hit lvl 13

Comment: Martial training gives you an initiator level equal to half your character level + whatever your modifier is correlating to the skill of the discipline. But im looking at it now and...why does the summary give you a separate description from the main one below? "While in this stance, unarmed or discipline weapon strikes inflict an additional 1d6 points of damage, +1d6 additional damage / eight initiator levels."

Comment: here we go its apparently an erreta http://bpfindley.com/PoWErrata.html

Comment: @Masakan  Excellent find! Errata incorporated into answer. (Although, at that point, another extra 3½ points of damage per attack really isn't really that big of a deal.)

Comment: I'll point out that with two levels of Master Of Many Styles, you could get Pummeling Style and then Pummeling Charge.
Combine that with a Path Of War initiator class, and you're good to punch well before L13.

Comment: @Frezak Yeah, MOMS should've been mentioned initially, but taking levels in an initiator class probably means delaying or significantly lowering the unarmed strike damage progression and the number of attacks from brawler's fury or flurry of blows, which, I think, is an important part of the question.

Comment: The linked "errata" is for a specific campaign run by a particular GM, and is not official errata. Indeed, at the top of that page it links to actual official errata, which makes no mention of pugilist stance. Given the full description of the stance does not grant a scaling bonus, and there is no official errata, it does not scale except in those games where the GM says it does.

Comment: @Eagle0600 You are, indeed, correct, sir. However, whether or not pugilist stance scales remains in the GM's hands not because the full description is, by the rules, considered more complete or anything but because, unlike *D&D 3.5*, [*Pathfinder* has no text-trumps-table rule.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/126038/8610) Nonetheless, I appreciate you checking my work, and I'll fix this posthaste.