# Does text trump tables?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In 3.5, there's a well-known rule that states "text trumps tables", viz. the text of an ability or class feature or whatever overrules a table provided that summarizes or collates said information.  This rule is a subset of the primary source rule in 3.5 and is found in the same document.

Pathfinder did away with Primary Sources in its errata structure, so said document is not functionally shared between the systems.  That said, when there's a contradiction between the text of an ability and a table summarizing the same, what happens?  Does the text overrule the table or vice versa or something else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81003/discussion-on-question-by-the-dark-wanderer-does-text-trump-tables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### As of 2015, there is no such rule.

**I also cannot find any official reference to it since then**, ref. [this forum post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2s37d?Whats-standardpractice-when-the-table-and) which was FAQ'd and never responded to by Paizo dev's. Until Paizo specifies its preferences, it is left up to groups to determine what makes the most sense to the GM and players.

For what it's worth, as you can also see in that forum, Paizo has instances of Errata'ing to support both text and tables, in different situations.

Comment: "As of 2015" I thought this was an old answer at first. "As of 2018" would probably fit the title better, considering the FAQ still has no answer.

Comment: I couldn't find a more recent source that indicated that it was unanswered, so sourcing-wise it's a correct headline. I'll emphasize the part where I clarify that I couldn't find a more recent source.